# Why is the 'scale' argument not being applied in my dollar_format() function

Tags: r, scale

I would be grateful if anyone could explain why the scale argument is not being applied in my dollar_format function.

usd_to_euro(100) returns the correct suffix but it remains 100 not 85.

```
library(scales)

usd_to_euro <- dollar_format(prefix = "", suffix = "\u20ac", scale = .85)

usd_to_euro(100)
```

Comment: When I run your code,  I get `"85€"`. Please start a fresh R session and run exactly the code in your question.

Comment: Hi G5W. Console: R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) -- "Feather Spray"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)Microsoft R Open 3.5.1
The enhanced R distribution from Microsoft
Microsoft packages Copyright (C) 2018 Microsoft Corporation

Using the Intel MKL for parallel mathematical computing (using 4 cores).

Default CRAN mirror snapshot taken on 2018-08-01.
See: https://mran.microsoft.com/.

> library(scales)
> 
> usd_to_euro <- dollar_format(prefix = "", suffix = "\u20ac", scale = .85)
> 
> usd_to_euro(100)
[1] "100€"

Comment: Very odd.  I am also using `R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) -- "Feather Spray" `

Comment: I'm using Microsoft R - my version is scales 0.5.0. G5W is yours scales 1.0.0? It looks like the scale argument was only added to dollar_format in that version.